# Can someone tell are there any bug fixes to skype on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, skype

Can someone tell me,are there any bug fixes to Skype on ubuntu 12.04?
when i closed Skype without signing off then after when i needed to reopen it before i restart the computer it won't work,"Already running " message appears, ie: it is running on the background!.yes i can kill the process and re-open it but it is not the way Skype should work!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late with an answer, but for future reference. One solution is to bring up the terminal, and physically kill the process(es).

```
ps aux | grep skype
```

Thus lists the skype processes, if any exists you will get a PID, and can kill it via.

```
sudo kill <pid>
```

Comment: not quite what he is asking I guess, he knows how to kill processes without opening a terminal

Comment: I understand, but I was assuming he wanted to quickly kill the process and restart it again. I'm also assuming he's using Unity, because in Gnome the easier solution is to get the tasks up (Windows key on win keyboard or "activities" top-right corner), and right-click or double-click the Skype Process (That's how I do it). But on Unity, I can only assume the quickest way is kill the process, and restart Skype.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to report bugs [here](https://developer.skype.com/SkypeGarage/ReportIssue). Not sure how they will respond to that...skype for linux is very very buggy and somewhat abandoned compared to Win and Mac. I found myself using Google talk more and more, although not perfect either.